# grab non-sibling element with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

So I am building a comment system and this HTML is my 'reply' area for each comment so it is printed as many times as there are comments. I am trying to grab the value of the text area that is right next to the submit button. I cannot figure out how to do this (I would be able to do this if they were sibling elements), so I am turning here for some help.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ticket-message" class="col-sm-1 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" id="reply_textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Try to be as specific as possible when replying!"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
        <button id="submit_reply_button" type="submit" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit Reply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery, which does not produce the desired result:

```
$("#submit_reply_button").click(function () {
         alert("firing");
         alert(($(this).closest('.form-group').prev("reply_textarea").val()));                                           
                                });
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's with that closing span tag inside the button?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out... just some junk from a previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could track it using the parent div with the class `form-group` and point to its previous peer:

```
$("#submit_reply_button").click(function () {
         alert("firing");
         alert(($(this).closest('.form-group').prev().find("#reply_textarea").val()));                                           
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/sp0yaq0y/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Works great. And this definitely helps me better understand jquery.